# There was a prblm parsing the package while installing .apk file of xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, webview

There was a problem parsing the package while installing .apk file.
Given below is configuration and code.
VS2015

MainActivity.cs

```
namespace WebAp
{
    [Activity(Label = "TC", MainLauncher = true, Theme ="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        private WebView web_view;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            web_view = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webview);
            web_view.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            web_view.LoadUrl("http://www.tc.com");
            web_view.SetWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
        }

        public class HelloWebViewClient : WebViewClient
        {
            public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, string url)
            {
                view.LoadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        }

        public override bool OnKeyDown(Android.Views.Keycode keyCode, Android.Views.KeyEvent e)
        {
            if (keyCode == Android.Views.Keycode.Back && web_view.CanGoBack())
            {
                web_view.GoBack();
                return true;
            }

            return base.OnKeyDown(keyCode, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Configurataion :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okHQj.png)
[image]

Thats it my code. I was also try different API for Compile, Min and target version.
Please help me thanks.

Comment: any log of console when you build the apk?

Comment: In Emulator it is working fine. i was run it with Android_Accelerated_x86(Android 6.0 - API 23) its working in emulator.

Comment: try the [guide](http://www.technicalnotes.org/fix-parse-error-in-android-there-is-a-problem-parsing-the-package/)